# Pandas merge dataframes adding line inbetween

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to merge some data frames on top of each other while adding a cell plus blank line in between.

Say I have 3 dfs. df1,df2,df3 and i also have a list = ["part1", "part2","part3"]

Im looking to merge the df so it looks like,

"part1"

df1

"part2"

df2

"part3"

df3

Whats a good way to do this?

Comment: What is the shape of your dataframes?  More than one column?  And you want part to be just in the first column?  What about creating a multiindex where index level 1 would be an indicator or your dataframes?

Comment: @ScottBoston its a multicolumn df. I am splitting one big df into parts. Then I would like to place the splits on top of each other with a line in between indicating what part it is.

Comment: And you want this to be a single dataframe?  Or are you just printing this out?

Comment: I can't think of a good reason to do this - there is probably a better way to do what you want.  Why do you want to separate your combined dfs with rows?

Comment: @anon01 I agree.

Comment: @anon01 I wanted to split them for easier viewing but I dont want multiple output files. So I am merging them together with markers to view them all in one go. Is this not recommended?

Comment: @llssff it is not recommended.  Adding non-data rows will break or cause side effects for many columnar operations such as `count`, `unique`, `shape`, etc.  You are better off 1) creating an `id` column that specifies the identity of the sub-dataframe or 2) keeping them as separate files (esp. if the tables are large, handled independently, or have different columns)

Comment: For example, based on `df1, df2, df3` defined in Scott's answer: `(df1["ID"], df2["ID"], df3["ID"]) = (1,2,3); df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3])` would be a more typical way to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC,

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,(5,5)), columns=[*'ABCDE'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,(8,5)), columns=[*'ABCDE'])
df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,(7,5)), columns=[*'ABCDE'])

l = ["part1", "part2","part3"]

pd.concat([pd.concat([pd.Series(lb), d]) for d, lb in zip([df1,df2, df3],l)], ignore_index=True).fillna(' ')
```

Output:

```
        0   A   B   C   D   E
0   part1                    
1           6  99  30  92  78
2          37  86  92  13  47
3          79   5  69  98  76
4          98  45  24  77  89
5          31  72  31  73  90
6   part2                    
7          18  18  89   9   5
8          71  74  34  77  20
9          90  93   5  37  47
10         31  80  59  54  54
11         17  77  48  68  34
12          9  31  22  89  70
13         35  87  97  41  76
14         59  91  23  74  34
15  part3                    
16         41  65  99  82  60
17         10  94  85  71  60
18         81   8  16  68   9
19         80  73  42   3  23
20         45  93  41  33  54
21         87   0  71  82   3
22         29  62   7  82  84
```